# Java Date get real offset

Tags: java, date

I want to get the real offset for a timezone.

My problem :

```
 TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Toronto");
int test = tz.getRawOffset();

test = -18000000

-18000000/1000/3600 = -5
```

Or if i go https://www.google.fr/search?q=horaire+toronto&oq=horaire+toro&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3311j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

i see Toronto is on UTC-4.

Its written on documentation , that the method return brut offset.

But how i can get the real offset ?

Comment: Another search with "toronto daylight savings" seems to indicate that they do have daylight savings applicable, and clocks are set forward in march... Worth looking into...

Comment: The `TimeZone` class is long outdated and the `getTimeZone` method that you use in particular can behave very surprisingly. I recommend you avoid the old date-time classes and learn to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) instead. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use getRawOffset

use : `tz.getOffset(new Date().getTime()) / 1000 / 3600`

Comment: These classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 5):

`getRawOffset` doesn't take DST into account. It reflects *standard time*. From the docs:

> Returns the amount of time in milliseconds to add to UTC to get **standard time** in this time zone. **Because this value is not affected by daylight saving time, it is called raw offset.**

Toronto is currently observing daylight saving time (until November 4th) so its current UTC offset is -4 hours, but that's -5 hours "standard" and +1 hour DST.

Now there's an inaccurate assumption there: that a time zone never changes its standard time. `java.util.TimeZone` is a relatively old and primitive representation; it would be better to use `java.time.ZoneId` instead, along with the rest of the `java.time` package.

If you *must* use `java.util.TimeZone`, then call `getOffset(long)` to get the UTC offset at a particular instant in time.

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` API is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Toronto");
        LocalDateTime ldtDstOn = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2018, Month.OCTOBER, 22), LocalTime.MIN);
        LocalDateTime ldtDstOff = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2018, Month.NOVEMBER, 22), LocalTime.MIN);

        // Using ZonedDateTime
        ZoneOffset offsetDstOn = ZonedDateTime.of(ldtDstOn, zoneId).getOffset();

        // Alternatively, using ZoneId#getRules
        ZoneOffset offsetDstOff = zoneId.getRules().getOffset(ldtDstOff);

        System.out.println(offsetDstOn);
        System.out.println(offsetDstOff);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
-04:00
-05:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/KxAI4s)

Verify with [Clock Changes in Toronto, Ontario, Canada 2018](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/canada/toronto?year=2018)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>